# Tengo el error "Array to string conversion" cuando leo un JSON

Tags: php, json

Tengo un problema cuando leo un *JSON* desde *PHP* porque no sé cómo acceder a cierto nivel.

Al ejecutar el código en *PHP*:

```
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$json_data = json_decode($json, true);
$var=$json_data['message']['published-print']['date-parts']['0'];
```

Obtengo el error:

> Array to string conversion

La estructura aproximada del *JSON*:

```
{
    "status": "ok",
    "message-type": "work",
    "message-version": "1.0.0",
    "message":{
        "indexed":{"...":"..."},
        "reference-count": 52,
        "publisher": "Elsevier BV",
        "license":["..."],
        "funder":["..."],
        "content-domain":["..."],
        "short-container-title":["..."],
        "cited-count": 0,
        "published-print":{
            "date-parts":[
                2017,
                2,
                "..."
            ]
        }
    },
    "...":"..."
}
```

Comment: Puedes agregar el error completo? Puedes agregar el Json con el que te arroja el error?

Answer (score 0):

Usaré este JSON como modelo:

```
{
    "title": "Person",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "firstName": "Pedro",
        "lastName": "Sánchez",
        "age": {
            "description": "Age in years",
            "type": "integer",
            "minimum": 0
        }
    },
    "required": ["firstName", "lastName"]
}
```

Las formas de acceder a un JSON son muchas (elemento por elemento, por array de elementos, dentro de un bucle...), todo depende de la estructura del mismo y del uso que quieras darle a los datos.

Puedes ir accediendo a los elementos por nivel. 
Ejemplo:

- Acceder al elemento firstName dentro de properties:

  `$json->properties->firstName;`
- Cuando el elemento al que accedes es un array como es el caso de required, en el ejemplo, accedes por el índice:

  `$json->required[0]`

Si el sub-array tiene muchos valores los puedes leer también con un iterador, con un bucle for o con un while.

Aquí muestro algunos ejemplos:

**[DEMO](http://ideone.com/Vq9oVM)**

```
<?php

$string_json='{
    "title": "Person",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "firstName": "Pedro",
        "lastName": "Sánchez",
        "age": {
            "description": "Age in years",
            "type": "integer",
            "minimum": 0
        }
    },
    "required": ["firstName", "lastName"]
}';

//Crar objeto json
$json=json_decode($string_json);

echo "Acceder por nombres de clave:\n";
echo "Valor de la clave title: ". $json->title;
echo "\nValor de la clave firstName (dentro de properties): ". $json->properties->firstName;
echo "\n\nAlgunas claves pueden tener arrays dentro";
echo "\nValores de required (Array): 1er elemento: ". $json->required[0]. " 2º elemento: ".$json->required[1];


//Iterando
echo "\nAcceder por iterator:\n";
iterator (json_decode($string_json,true));

echo "\nSi no se conoce el contenido y la estructura se puede usar print_r:\n";
print_r ($json);

function iterator ($json)
{
$jsonIterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveArrayIterator($json),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

foreach ($jsonIterator as $key => $val) {
    if(is_array($val)) {
        echo "$key:\n";
    } else {
        echo "$key => $val\n";
    }
}
}
```

**RESULTADO**

> ```
> Acceder por nombres de clave:
> Valor de la clave title: Person
> Valor de la propiedad firstName: Pedro
>
> Algunas claves pueden tener arrays dentro
> Valores de required (Array): 1er elemento: firstName 2º elemento: lastName
>
> Acceder por iterator:
> title => Person
> type => object
> properties:
> firstName => Pedro
> lastName => Sánchez
> age:
> description => Age in years
> type => integer
> minimum => 0
> required:
> 0 => firstName
> 1 => lastName
>
> Si no se conoce el contenido y la estructura se puede usar print_r:
> stdClass Object
> (
>     [title] => Person
>     [type] => object
>     [properties] => stdClass Object
>         (
>             [firstName] => Pedro
>             [lastName] => Sánchez
>             [age] => stdClass Object
>                 (
>                     [description] => Age in years
>                     [type] => integer
>                     [minimum] => 0
>                 )
>
>         )
>
>     [required] => Array
>         (
>             [0] => firstName
>             [1] => lastName
>         )
>
> )
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Si tu conversion del JSON al array asociativo fue exitosa, lo puedes verificar con

```
print_r($json_data);
```

De haber sido exitosa entonces,estas accediendo al indice como texto:

```
$var=$json_data['message']['published-print']['date-parts']['0'];
```

deberia de ser:

```
$var=$json_data['message']['published-print']['date-parts'][0];
```

O tambien puede ser que estes intentando hacer un echo a un array u objeto.